# Command binding not working inside Listview in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, prism

I am trying to bind a command to TapGesture to a Frame inside the list view control. Frame is defined inside the datatemplate for the list view.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding LstSrc}"                    
                    RowHeight="75" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                  <Grid Margin="0"
                        Padding="0"
                        BackgroundColor="White">                  
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>                         
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Frame Grid.Column="0" BindingContext="{Binding Item1}"
                        Margin="0" Padding="0" x:Name="f1">
                      <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.GoToPageCommand, Source={x:Reference this}}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding BindingContext.Id, Source={x:Reference f1}}"/>
                      </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                       </Frame>                    
                  </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
```

Here LstSrc and GoToPageCommand ae defined in the viewmodel class. And Item1 is defined inside LstSrc.

Delegate Command defined inside view model is

```
 public DelegateCommand<TappedEventArgs> GoToPageCommand => new DelegateCommand<TappedEventArgs>(
           async s => {                            
               await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("NextPage");              
           });
```

But on tapping, the control is not coming to the command method.

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify BindingContext in your binding, if you look in the debug output window you will probably see binding errors. Try just binding to GoToPageCommand without the BindingContext in the binding path.

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't use bindings, but it should work if you're okay with taking a different approach.

```
<Frame.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer
              Tapped="OnFrameClicked"
              NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
</Frame.GestureRecognizers>

void async OnFrameClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("NextPage"); 
}
```